# How to organize qml (QT) code and instances between different files

Tags: c++, qt, qml

I have an application with c++ back end and a qml GUI. This GUI exists of multiple qml files (FluidControls.Pages) that are dynamically loaded given the pressing of a button in a side panel (see picture below).

How can I organize qml code and instances between those different pages (in separate qml files)?

For example, the triangular icon in the top right corner indicates if an error occurs in the C++ back end, and upon clicking this item a popup with the log messages appears.
Every qml file/page has a property "actions" like this:

```
actions: [
    FluidControls.Action {
        id:log_action
        icon.source: FluidControls.Utils.iconUrl("alert/warning")
    },
    ... more actions
]
Connections {
    target: guiApp
    onInfo:{
       log_action.icon.color = "red";
       showError()
    }
}
```

However this has the following problems:

- code is repeated (minor problem)
- the connections are re-instantiated upon every load of the page, resulting in multiple invocations of showError (major problem)

So I would like to reuse the code and the defined Actions instance, so I've created an Actions.qml file like this:

```
Item {
property var actions: [
    FluidControls.Action {
    id:log_action
    icon.source: FluidControls.Utils.iconUrl("alert/warning")
    },
    ... more actions
]
Connections {
    target: guiApp
    onInfo:{
       log_action.icon.color = "red";
    }
}
```

and assigned this 1 instance to the property of the pages:

```
actions: Actions.actions
```

However this results in a error "Expected token `,'" on the line: FluidControls.Action {
How can I get this working and resolve the problems stated above (Is the approach correct or should I subclass the FluidControls.Page or do something else)?
[image: qml app with multiple pages]